# Работает ли include в Вижуал студио?

Tags: html

Подскажите, изучаю хтмл, счас пробую с include вставки делать. Пишу в вижуал студио, а include не работает, или он только с локальным сервером будет работать?

собственно код простейший, чтобы разобраться с технологией работы инклуд. Оба файла в едином проекте.
Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <title></title>  

</head>  
<body>  
    <h1>Тут внешний параграф</h1>   
    <!--#include virtual="one.html"-->  

</body>
```

И

one.html

```
<p>тут параграф</p>
```

Comment: Э-э... Вообще-то Visual Studio — это по языкам *программирования* для написания программ и библиотек, а HTML — язык *разметки* Web-страниц. Каким боком здесь студия?

Comment: @Arhad, студия - это прежде всего редактор, в котором, в том числе, можно редактировать и html страницы

Comment: Покажи, что именно ты пробуешь делаешь

Comment: @Grundy, то есть спрашивающий пытается использовать сишную директиву `#include` в HTML коде?

Comment: @Arhad, скорее всего не сишную, но чтобы точно сказать, нужен пример кода автора

Comment: @Arhad `<!--#include virtual="menu.cgi" -->` - это валиндая директива для server side includes - базового движка, который можно доставить как опцию в IIS

Comment: Сам по себе html ничего ни о каких include'ах не знает, не умеет и VS вообще-то тоже. Но если у тебя есть настроенный gulp, с плагином, инклюдящим куски html в места include'ов, то можно настроить VS, чтобы она запускала gulp.

Comment: @Qwertiy как вариант для особо затейлевых господ - использовать препроцессор C/C++ студии для подключения через инклюды.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, http://govnokod.ru/18440 & http://govnokod.ru/11549

Comment: @PashaPash, отвечать будешь?